# Python 2.7 reading a new line in CSV and store it as variable

Tags: python, csv

I am using the code below to read the last line of my csv. file which
is constantly updated and is working great. I am receiving the last line
and it is consisted of 11 values which are comma separated. It goes like:

10/16/16, -1, false,  4:00:00 PM, 4585 , .......etc

Now I want to take the values from column 6 and 9 for example and store them
as two separate variables and later use them as a conditions. Is there simple way to add just few lines to the existing code to achieve this or i have to write a new code?

```
import time, os

#Set the filename and open the file
filename = 'Test.csv'
file = open(filename,'r')

#Find the size of the file and move to the end
st_results = os.stat(filename)
st_size = st_results[6]
file.seek(st_size)

while 1:`enter code here`
    where = file.tell()
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        time.sleep(0.5)`enter code here`
        file.seek(where)
    else:
        print line, # already has newline
```

Comment: Am, split the line on `,` and index?

Comment: Why are you not just using the `csv` module?

Comment: Why are you using `time.sleep()`? Also, please read over your code before you hit the `Post Question` button. You have 2 extraneous spots with `\`enter code here\``.

Comment: Using `os.stat(filename)` to get the file size to then seek to the end of it is unnecessary. Just use `f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)`. And avoid using `file` as a variable name - it shadows the builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can just add a few line in there to get what you want. I would delim each line by comma using `line.split(',')`. This will return an array like this `['10/16/16', '-1', 'false', '4:00:00 PM', '4585' ]`. Then you can simply save the array at index 6 ~ 9 for your convenience and use it later in the code.

Ex)

```
while 1:`enter code here`
where = file.tell()
line = file.readline()
if not line:
    time.sleep(0.5)`enter code here`
    file.seek(where)
else:
    arr_line = line.split(',')
    var6 = arr_line[6]
    var7 = arr_line[7]
    var8 = arr_line[8]
    var9 = arr_line[9]

    # other code ...

    print line
```